# Cross elegant tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabularray

I wanted to create a table like this where there are right spacing and where the table has the lines a little bit thicker.

[image]

Original solutions that do not faithfully reflect the proposed image are appreciated.

I add a not compilable MWE :-(.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\[     
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
x & -4 & -2 & -\frac 12 & \frac1{16} & \frac18 & \frac14 &1\\ 
\hline 
y & -\frac1{32} & -\frac1{16} & -\frac14 & 2 &1 & \frac 12 &\frac 18\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is "right spacing"? do you mean right spacing and right scaling?

Comment: @BlackMild Yes right spacing and right scaling! Excuse me always for my bad English language.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, using the package `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ c|*7{Q[c,m]} },
    hline{2}=1pt,
    vline{2}=1pt,
    rowsep=2mm,
    colsep=5mm
  } 
x & -4 & -2 & -\frac 12 & \frac1{16} & \frac18 & \frac14 &1\\ 
y & -\frac1{32} & -\frac1{16} & -\frac14 & 2 &1 & \frac 12 &\frac 18\\ 
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs the `w` column type, which is provided by the `array` package, and the macros `\addlinespace` and `\midrule`, both provided by the `booktabs` package. All cell widths are set to `1cm`; you're obviously free to choose a different value.

[image]

If you want the horizontal line to be even thicker, I suggest you replace `\midrule` with `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,
            array,    % for 'w' column type
            booktabs} % for \midrule and \addlinespace macros
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman text and math font)

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ wl{1cm} *{7}{>{\displaystyle}wc{1cm}} @{}}
x & -4 & -2 & -\frac 12 & \frac1{16} & \frac18 & \frac14 & 1 \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\addlinespace
y & -\frac1{32} & -\frac1{16} & -\frac14 & 2 & 1 & \frac12 & \frac 18
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dearest Mico, I have been feeling a little better for a few weeks now. Thank you very much for your answer. The vertical line next to x and y is missing.

Comment: Dearest Sebastiano. So glad to hear you're feeling better once more. On the missing vertical bar: I was just following your comment that "Original solutions that do not faithfully reflect the proposed image are appreciated."  :-)  Speaking (obviously!) for myself, I find that whitespace can be every bit as good as a solid line in providing visual separation. Hence, is the vertical line either needed or helpful?

Answer (score 2):

This is my plain TikZ suggestion.  Right spacing and right scaling are up to you ^^

I use `[xscale=1.5,yscale=1.2]` to control horizontal and vertical scalings; also fractions can be inserted with `\frac`, `\dfrac`, and the `scale` node option. You are free to change drawing options like `opacity`, `color`, `line width`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=1.2]
\path 
(0,0)   node{$x$}    % the 1st line
++(0:1) node{$-4$}
++(0:1) node{$-2$}
++(0:1) node{$-\dfrac{1}{2}$}
++(0:1) node{$\dfrac{1}{16}$}
++(0:1) node{$\dfrac{1}{8}$}
++(0:1) node{$\dfrac{1}{4}$}
++(0:1) node{$1$}
(0,-1)  node{$y$}   % the 2nd line
++(0:1) node{$-\dfrac{1}{32}$}
++(0:1) node{$-\dfrac{1}{16}$}
++(0:1) node{$-\dfrac{1}{4}$}
++(0:1) node{$2$}
++(0:1) node{$1$}
++(0:1) node{$\dfrac{1}{2}$}
++(0:1) node{$\dfrac{1}{8}$}
;
\draw[line width=1pt,magenta] (.5,.5)--+(-90:2) (-.5,-.5)--++(0:8);     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```